# How to fix laravel 8 UI paginate problem not working

Tags: php, laravel

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Post')

@section('contents')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                {{ $post->title }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                {{ $post->body }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                {{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="d-felx justify-content-center">

            {{ $posts->links() }}

        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

I had a problem while trying out the recently released laravel 8, I'm trying to find out what the changes are and how it works. When I did that I had a problem with the paginate laravel 8 UI getting messy and somehow it happened. Is there anyone who can help me? or have experienced the same thing?

Comment: Exactly what is the issue, and what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

By messy I think what you imply here is that the elements are out place.
Laravel 8 uses tailwind css.
If it's the problem and you have queried it correctly with `paginate()`
then what you can do is, use bootstrap.

Simply add the following code in `AppServiceProvider` file and it will use bootstrap for paginate styling.

```
    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Bootstrap any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
            Paginator::useBootstrap(); //this line will be in boot method*
        }

    
}
```